# Match To single Row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, opencart

[image]

There is a list of Filter Id assigned to Products.
Multiple Filter Can be assigned to Same Product.
So i am looking for the query to fetch product id if according to passed filter id

eg I have

```
$filter_id = Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 12
    ...
 )
```

In this case it should return product id 40 I need all filter id matched to get particular product so i used AND

I tried 
SELECT product_id FROM tablename WHERE filter_id = 2 AND filter_id = 12

Thanks

Comment: yes so what exactly is the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how u can do to find the product which has both 2,12 as filter_id.

```
select product_id
from products
where filter_id in (2,12) 
group by product_id
having count(distinct filter_id) = 2
```

You need to change

```
having count(distinct filter_id) = 2
```

to the number of filter_id you are checking.

Just using `filter_id in (2,12)` to your query will return all the product which has 2 or 12.

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0c8d/8)**

Answer (score 1):

Your query

```
SELECT product_id FROM tablename WHERE filter_id = 2 AND filter_id = 12
```

will return **0 rows** as there can't be a row having filterid equal to 2 and 12 at sametime , it is **impossible** in relational database design

Instead use [IN operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) to specify multiple required values for a column .

```
SELECT product_id FROM tablename WHERE filter_id IN(2,12)
```